# Disable select elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which simply disables all `select` elements using following line of code

```
$('select').prop('disabled', true);
```

It works fine for all those select elements which already exist in DOM, however. There are several places where `select` elements are added using javascript/jquery. And above line of code does not disable those elements. One way to work around is that call that particular plugin everytime those `select` elements are added to the DOM but this would be a lot of work and needs.

**Is there a better way to disable all these select elements?**

Comment: You can simply add `disabled` attribute while creating.

Comment: Again I will have to go through entire application which to find those occurances. I need a better way to that I don't have to go through and find those places and add disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can try somoething like this:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'select', function () {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

EDIT: it seems that **DOMNodeInserted** is deprecated. So you should use **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage)**.

If you need IE9/10 support you can take a look at **[Polyfill](https://github.com/Polymer/MutationObservers)**.

Comment: DOMNodeInserted seems to deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: you're right, try to use MutationObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage

Comment: I am already looking at it but browser compatibility is a b it of an issue there. I need to support at least IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="myBtn" href="#">Insert select</a>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {        

        $("#myBtn").click(function() {
            $("body").prepend("<select></select>");
        }); 


        $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
            if (e.target.tagName === "SELECT") {
                console.log("doing stuff!");
            } 
        }); 


    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: DOMNodeInserted is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'select', function () {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```